# How to properly re-layout a graph and center on a node

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I'm using *cytoscape* to dynamically create a network visualisation and I'm having trouble to setup the layout correctly.
Occasionally, a collection of nodes is created and attached to a parent `node`.
Then I call the following function to **layout** the new nodes and **center** the graph on that parent:

```
static DoLayout(node) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cy.layout({
            name: 'cose',
            fit: false,
            nodeRepulsion: function (node) { return 99999; },
            componentSpacing: 100,
            padding: 100,
            randomize: false,
            animate: 'end',
            animationEasing: 'ease-in-out',
            animationDuration: 350,
            stop: () => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    cy.zoom(.8)
                    cy.center(node);
                }, 100);
            }
        })
            .run();

    }, 50);

}
```

And here's the issue:
[image]

Is there a possibility to have these three actions *layout*, *center* and *zoom* happen at the same time? Or smoothly?

**Edit:** (`fit: true,`)

Setting `fit` to `true`, as suggested by [canbax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3209523/canbax), solves the 'flickering' issue shown in the gif. However it still doesn't produce a smooth transition (animation?) when zooming and centering. Plus, I don't want the graph to be completely zoomed-out then zoomed-in and centered.

Comment: set `fit: true,`

Comment: @canbax yes it solves the first issue: 'flickering', however I don't want to fit to the hole graph each time I add new node, and also zoom/center isn't done smoothly, I'll update my question..

Comment: some layout algorithms support incremental layout. For example, fcose supports this. just pass option `randomize: false`.  https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-fcose/

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I was looking for: incremental layout. But I couldn't have the same results with same options I used with cose layout. Now the nodes are overlapping and also not well centered on main node: https://pasteboard.co/iWZeLX3Hhrro.png.

Comment: Additionally you can use https://github.com/iVis-at-Bilkent/cytoscape.js-layout-utilities/ with `placeNewNodes` method you can place new nodes into positions

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't achieve the desired result. I managed to have the app live [here](https://data4v1.herokuapp.com/) so you can see the problem. Feel free to check it out, and thanks in advance.